# Inverse CDF sampling for a mixed distribution

Tags: r, distributions, sampling, simulation, copula

#### The out-of-context short version

Let $y$ be a random variable with CDF
$$
F(\cdot) \equiv \cases{\theta & y = 0 \\ \theta + (1-\theta) \times \text{CDF}_{\text{log-normal}}(\cdot; \mu, \sigma) & y > 0}
$$

Let's say I wanted to simulate draws of $y$ using the inverse CDF method. Is that possible? This function doesn't exactly have an inverse. Then again there's [Inverse transformation sampling for mixture distribution of two normal distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/73028/36) which suggests that there is a known way to apply inverse transformation sampling here.

I'm aware of the two-step method, but I don't know how to apply it to my situation (see below).

---

#### The long version with background

I fitted the following model for a vector-valued response, $y^i = \left( y_1 , \dots , y_K \right)^i$, using MCMC (specifically, Stan):

$$
\theta_k^i \equiv \operatorname{logit}^{-1}\left( \alpha_k x^i \right), \quad \mu_k^i \equiv \beta_k x^i - \frac{ \sigma^2_k }{ 2 } \\
F(\cdot) \equiv \cases{\theta & y = 0 \\ \theta + (1-\theta) \times \text{CDF}_{\text{log-normal}}(\cdot; \mu, \sigma) & y > 0} \\
u_k \equiv F(y_k), \quad z_k \equiv\Phi^{-1}{\left( u_k \right)} \\
z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, R) \times \prod_k f(y_k) \\
\left( \alpha, \beta, \sigma, R \right) \sim \text{priors}
$$

where $i$ indexes $N$ observations, $R$ is a correlation matrix, and $x$ is a vector of predictors/regressors/features.

That is, my model is a regression model in which the conditional distribution of the response is assumed to be a Gaussian copula with zero-inflated log-normal marginals. I've posted about this model before; it turns out that Song, Li, and Yuan (2009, [gated](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1541-0420.2008.01058.x/abstract)) have developed it and they call it a vector GLM, or VGLM. The following is their specification as close to verbatim as I could get it:
$$
f(\mathbf{y}; \mathbf{\mu}, \mathbf{\varphi}, \Gamma) = c\{ G_1(y_1), \dots, G_m(y_m) | \Gamma \} \prod_{i=1}^m g(y_i; \mu_i, \varphi_i) \\
c(\mathbf{u} | \Gamma) = \left| \Gamma \right|^{-1/2}\exp\left( \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{q}^T \left( I_m - \Gamma^{-1} \right) \mathbf{q} \right) \\
\mathbf{q} = \left( q_1, \dots, q_m \right)^T, \quad q_i = \Phi^{-1}(u_i)
$$
My $F_K$ corresponds to their $G_m$, my $z$ corresponds to their $\mathbf{q}$, and my $R$ corresponds to their $\Gamma$; the details are on page 62 (page 3 of the PDF file) but they're otherwise identical to what I wrote here.

The zero-inflated part roughly follows the specification of Liu and Chan (2010, [ungated](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v35/i11/paper)).

Now I would like to simulate data from the estimated parameters, but I'm a little confused as to how to go about it. First I thought I could just simulate $y$ directly (in R code):

```
for (i in 1:N) {
    for (k in 1:K) {
        Y_hat <- rbinom(1, 1, 1 - theta[i, k])
        if (Y_hat == 1)
            Y_hat <- rlnorm(1, mu[i, k], sigma[k])
    }
}
```

which doesn't use $R$ at all. I'd like to try to actually use the correlation matrix I estimated.

My next idea was to take draws of $z$ and then convert them back to $y$. This also seems to coincide with the answers in [Generating samples from Copula in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/78894/36229) and [Bivariate sampling for distribution expressed in Sklar's copula theorem?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/123698/36229). But what the heck is my $F^{-1}$ here? [Inverse transformation sampling for mixture distribution of two normal distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/73028/36229) makes it sound like this is possible, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: @Xi'an it's a Gaussian copula, for estimating the dependence among the $y$ components.

Comment: The thread you reference about sampling from mixtures of Normals applies directly to your problem with no essential modification: instead of using the inverse CDFs of Normals, use the inverse CDFs of your two components.  The inverse CDF of the atom at $y=0$ is the constant function, always equal to $0$.

Comment: @whuber I'm just confused about _how_ to use the inverse CDFs of the two components: what do I draw, what do I draw it from, and then what do I plug each thing into?

Comment: @Xi'an nicely explains that in his answer to the normal-mixture question: you use a uniform variate to select the mixture component and then you draw a value from that component (in any way you like). In your case it's exceptionally easy to draw a value from the first component: it's always $0$! To draw a value from the second component use any lognormal random number generator you like. In each case you wind up with a number: there's no "plugging in" to accomplish; the whole objective of random number generation is to obtain that number.

Comment: @whuber the new answer cleared it up for me. Thank you both.

Comment: Out of curosity, what is the application you have for this model?  It's an interesting one.

Comment: @AndrewM I'm modeling college students' time use (a vector) as a function of their previous year's time use and some covariates

Comment: Of course, now that I'm thinking about it this probably could have been accomplished with variance components / random effects

Comment: Actually, I wonder if this is actually _equivalent_ to random effects. @Xi'an's answer makes me think that it is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The answer to the long version with background:**

This answer to the long version somewhat addresses another issue and,
since we seem to have difficulties formulating the model and the problem, I choose to rephrase it here, hopefully correctly.

For $1\le i\le I$, the goal is to simulate vectors $y^i=(y^i_1,\ldots,y^i_K)$ such that, conditional on a covariate $x^i$,
$$
y_k^i = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{ with probability }\operatorname{logit}^{-1}\left( \alpha_k x^i \right)\\
\log(\sigma_k z_k^i + \beta_k x^i) &\text{ with probability }1-\operatorname{logit}^{-1}\left( \alpha_k x^i \right)\end{cases}
$$
with $z^i=(z^i_1,\ldots,z^i_K)\sim\mathcal{N}_K(0,R)$. Hence, if one wants to simulate data from this model, one could proceed as follows:

For $1\le i\le I$,

1. Generate $z^i=(z^i_1,\ldots,z^i_K)\sim\mathcal{N}_K(0,R)$
2. Generate $u^i_1,\ldots,u^i_K \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} \mathcal{U}(0,1)$
3. Derive $y^i_k=\mathbb{I}\left\{u^i_k>\operatorname{logit}^{-1}\left( \alpha_k x^i \right)\right\}\, \log\{ \sigma_k z_k^i + \beta_k x^i\}$ for $1\le k\le K$

If one is interested in the generation from the posterior of $(\alpha,\beta,\mu,\sigma,R)$ given the $y^i_ k$, this is a harder problem, albeit feasible by Gibbs sampling or ABC.

Comment: I knew I was missing something. "Everything is obvious in hindsight." My intent: I'm interested in the value of $F(y^i | x^i)$, so yes, I'm interested in drawing from the joint posterior of the parameters. I want the simulated $y$'s to see if the model fits.

Comment: How is the second problem much harder? I've already estimated the model and I have posterior draws. We can continue in chat if you want, to keep from cluttering up the comments here.

Comment: Oh, in general, yeah. Fortunately I have Stan and the No-U-Turn Sampler doing the hard work for me there.

Answer (score 9):

**The answer to the out-of-context short version:**

"Inverting" a cdf that is not invertible in the mathematical sense (like your mixed distribution) is feasible, as described in most Monte Carlo textbooks. (Like [ours](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441915753), see Lemma 2.4.) If you define the generalised inverse
$$
F^{-}(u) = \inf\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R};\ F(x)\ge u \right\}
$$
then 
$$
X \sim F \text{ is equivalent to } X=F^{-}(U)\text{ when } U\sim\mathcal{U}(0,1)\,.
$$
This means that, when $F(y)$ has a jump of $\theta$ at $y=0$, $F^{-}(u)=0$ for $u\le\theta$. In other words, if you draw a uniform $\mathcal{U}(0,1)$ and it ends up smaller than $\theta$, your generation of $X$ is $x=0$. Else, when $u>\theta$, you end up generating from the continuous part, namely the log-normal in your case. This means using a second uniform random generation, $v$, independent from the first uniform draw and setting $y=\exp(\mu+\sigma\Phi^{-1}(v))$ to obtain a log-normal generation.

This is *almost* what your R code

`Y_hat <- rbinom(1, 1, theta[i, k])
        if (Y_hat == 1)
            Y_hat <- rlnorm(1, mu[i, k], sigma[k])`

is doing. You generate a Bernoulli with probability $\theta_k^i$ and if it is equal to $1$, you turn it into a log-normal. Since it is equal to 1 with probability $\theta_k^i$ you should *instead* turn it into a log-normal simulation when it is equal to *zero* instead, ending up with the modified R code:

```
Y_hat <- rbinom(1, 1, theta[i, k])
    if (Y_hat == 0)
        Y_hat <- rlnorm(1, mu[i, k], sigma[k])
```

Comment: So all together, my simulation procedure would be: 1) draw $z$, 2) compute $u_k = \Phi(z_k)$, then 3) compute $y_k = 0$ if $u_k \leq \theta$ and $y_k = F^{-1}_\text{log-normal}(u_k)$ otherwise. Correct?

Comment: No, incorrect. You draw a first uniform to decide between $0$ and log-normal, then a second uniform in case you have decided for a log-normal. See the edited version of my answer.

Comment: But that ignores the $z$ component; hence my question. I made a clarifying edit, and also addressed the mistake in my pseudocode.

Comment: My answer is for the short version and for the R code you provided. I hope it helps for the long-version, but your formula for the joint model is still incorrect. You should define the model on the $y$'s without using the uniforms...

Comment: How is that model incorrect? I just plugged my $F_1, \dots, F_K$ into the formula provided by the paper I cited (corresponding to $G_1, \dots, G_m$ in their notation). Is that invalid?

Comment: I edited their model into my question for those of us who don't have library access.